# Audio API center visualisation on frequency

Tags: javascript, typescript, audio, web-audio-api

I am working on an audio visualizer for the web that also lets the user "tune" the raw audio signal visualizer to a frequency. This is a feature of many hardware oscilloscopes. Basically, when a user centers on 440Hz and I have a 440Hz sine wave, the wave should stay still on the canvas and not move left or right. My plan was to move the graph to the left according to the frequency (440Hz = 1/440s to the left per second because the wave should repeat every 1/440s), but this does not work as it seems.

I could not find the units used by the Audio Analyzer Node's time domain data. I guess that it's in milliseconds, but I am not certain.

```js
"use strict";
// Oscillator instead of mic for debugging
const USE_OSCILLATOR = true;
// Compatibility
if (!window.AudioContext)
    window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia =
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
// Main
class App {
    constructor(visualizerElement, optionsElement) {
        this.visualizerElement = visualizerElement;
        this.optionsElement = optionsElement;
        // HTML elements
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        // Context
        this.context = new AudioContext({
            // Low latency
            latencyHint: "interactive",
        });
        this.canvasCtx = this.canvas.getContext("2d", {
            // Low latency
            desynchronized: true,
            alpha: false,
        });
        // Audio nodes
        this.audioAnalyser = this.context.createAnalyser();
        this.audioBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.audioAnalyser.frequencyBinCount);
        this.audioInputStream = null;
        this.audioInputNode = null;
        if (this.canvasCtx === null)
            throw new Error("2D rendering Context not supported by browser.");
        this.updateCanvasSize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.updateCanvasSize());
        this.drawVisualizer();
        this.visualizerElement.appendChild(this.canvas);
        if (USE_OSCILLATOR) {
            let oscillator = this.context.createOscillator();
            oscillator.type = "sine";
            oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, this.context.currentTime);
            oscillator.connect(this.audioAnalyser);
            oscillator.start();
        }
        else {
            navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, (stream) => {
                this.audioInputStream = stream;
                this.audioInputNode = this.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                this.audioInputNode.channelCountMode = "explicit";
                this.audioInputNode.channelCount = 1;
                this.audioBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.audioAnalyser.frequencyBinCount);
                this.audioInputNode.connect(this.audioAnalyser);
            }, (err) => console.error(err));
        }
    }
    updateCanvasSize() {
        var _a;
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        (_a = this.canvasCtx) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, this.canvas.height * 0.5);
    }
    drawVisualizer() {
        if (this.canvasCtx === null)
            return;
        const ctx = this.canvasCtx;
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, -0.5 * this.canvas.height, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        // Draw FFT
        this.audioAnalyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.audioBuffer);
        const step = this.canvas.width / this.audioBuffer.length;
        const scale = this.canvas.height / (2 * 255);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-step, this.audioBuffer[0] * scale);
        this.audioBuffer.forEach((sample, index) => {
            ctx.lineTo(index * step, scale * sample);
        });
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.stroke();
        // Get the highest dominant frequency
        let highestFreqHalfHz = 0;
        {
            /**
             * Highest frequency in 0.5Hz
             */
            let highestFreq = NaN;
            let highestFreqAmp = NaN;
            let remSteps = NaN;
            for (let i = this.audioBuffer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                const sample = this.audioBuffer[i];
                if (sample > 20 && (isNaN(highestFreqAmp) || sample > highestFreqAmp)) {
                    highestFreq = i;
                    highestFreqAmp = sample;
                    if (isNaN(remSteps))
                        remSteps = 500;
                }
                if (!isNaN(remSteps)) {
                    if (remSteps-- < 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (!isNaN(highestFreq)) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(highestFreq * step, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(highestFreq * step, scale * 255);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
                ctx.stroke();
                highestFreqHalfHz = highestFreq;
            }
        }
        // Draw Audio
        this.audioAnalyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.audioBuffer);
        {
            const bufferSize = this.audioBuffer.length;
            const offsetY = -this.canvas.height * 0.5;
            // I don't know what I am doing here:
            const offsetX = highestFreqHalfHz == 0
                ? 0
                : bufferSize -
                    Math.round(((this.context.currentTime * 1000) % (1 / 440)) % bufferSize);
            // Draw the audio graph with the given offset
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-step, this.audioBuffer[0] * scale + offsetY);
            for (let i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
                const index = (offsetX + i) % bufferSize;
                const sample = this.audioBuffer[index];
                ctx.lineTo(i * step, scale * sample + offsetY);
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const app = new App(document.getElementById("visualizer"), document.getElementById("options"));
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    function draw() {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        app.drawVisualizer();
    }
});
```

```css
html {
    background: black;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#visualizer {
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Equalizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="visualizer"></div>
    <div id="options"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above snippet was generated from TypeScript. You can find the source [here](https://gist.github.com/ColinTimBarndt/72e2a14a13a8f1df61b07131517b4425). If it worked as intended, the oscillating graph (bottom) would not be moving.

Comment: The values from `AnalyserNode.getFloatTimeDomainData` (and `getByteTimeDomainData`) are the actual time samples.  A sample occurs every `1/context.sampleRate` sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem thanks to [Raymond Toy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891195/audio-api-center-visualisation-on-frequency?noredirect=1#comment116504999_65891195) and my maths teacher (thank you Mr. Klein). The solution was `Math.round((this.context.currentTime % iv) * sampleRate)` where `iv` is the interval of the frequency (`1/Hz`). The wave is not perfectly centered. The FFT approximation is not very accurate though. In the following example I forced the detected frequency to be the specified one.

```js
"use strict";
// Oscillator instead of mic for debugging
const USE_OSCILLATOR = true;
const OSCILLATOR_HZ = 1000;
// Compatibility
if (!window.AudioContext)
    window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia =
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
// Main
class App {
    constructor(visualizerElement, optionsElement) {
        this.visualizerElement = visualizerElement;
        this.optionsElement = optionsElement;
        // HTML elements
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        // Context
        this.context = new AudioContext({
            // Low latency
            latencyHint: "interactive",
        });
        this.canvasCtx = this.canvas.getContext("2d", {
            // Low latency
            desynchronized: true,
            alpha: false,
        });
        // Audio nodes
        this.audioAnalyser = this.context.createAnalyser();
        this.audioBuffer = new Uint8Array(0);
        this.audioInputStream = null;
        this.audioInputNode = null;
        if (this.canvasCtx === null)
            throw new Error("2D rendering Context not supported by browser.");
        this.updateCanvasSize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.updateCanvasSize());
        this.drawVisualizer();
        this.visualizerElement.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.audioAnalyser.fftSize = 2048;
        this.audioAnalyser.maxDecibels = -10;
        this.audioBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.audioAnalyser.frequencyBinCount * 2);
        this.audioFilter = this.context.createBiquadFilter();
        this.audioFilter.type = "bandpass";
        this.audioFilter.frequency.value = 900;
        this.audioFilter.Q.value = 20;
        this.audioAmplifier = this.context.createGain();
        this.audioAmplifier.gain.value = 5;
        this.audioFilter.connect(this.audioAmplifier);
        this.audioAmplifier.connect(this.audioAnalyser);
        if (USE_OSCILLATOR) {
            let oscillator = this.context.createOscillator();
            oscillator.type = "sine";
            oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(OSCILLATOR_HZ, this.context.currentTime);
            oscillator.connect(this.audioFilter);
            oscillator.start();
        }
        else {
            navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, (stream) => {
                this.audioInputStream = stream;
                this.audioInputNode = this.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                this.audioInputNode.channelCountMode = "explicit";
                this.audioInputNode.channelCount = 1;
                this.audioBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.audioAnalyser.frequencyBinCount);
                this.audioInputNode.connect(this.audioFilter);
            }, (err) => console.error(err));
        }
    }
    updateCanvasSize() {
        var _a;
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        (_a = this.canvasCtx) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, this.canvas.height * 0.5);
    }
    drawVisualizer() {
        if (this.canvasCtx === null)
            return;
        const ctx = this.canvasCtx;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, -0.5 * this.canvas.height, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        // Draw FFT
        this.audioAnalyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.audioBuffer);
        const scale = this.canvas.height / (2 * 255);
        const { frequencyBinCount } = this.audioAnalyser;
        const { sampleRate } = this.context;
        {
            const step = this.canvas.width / frequencyBinCount;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-step, this.audioBuffer[0] * scale);
            for (let index = 0; index < frequencyBinCount; index++) {
                ctx.lineTo(index * step, scale * this.audioBuffer[index]);
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        // Get the highest dominant frequency
        const step = this.canvas.width / frequencyBinCount;
        let highestFreqHz = 0;
        {
            /**
             * Highest frequency index in the buffer
             */
            let highestFreqIndex = NaN;
            let highestFreqAmp = NaN;
            let remSteps = NaN;
            for (let i = frequencyBinCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                const sample = this.audioBuffer[i];
                if (sample > 30) {
                    if (isNaN(highestFreqAmp)) {
                        highestFreqIndex = i;
                        highestFreqAmp = sample;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (sample > highestFreqAmp) {
                            highestFreqIndex = i;
                            highestFreqAmp = sample;
                        }
                    }
                    //if (isNaN(remSteps)) remSteps = 100;
                }
                if (!isNaN(remSteps)) {
                    if (remSteps-- < 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (!isNaN(highestFreqIndex)) {
                // Force exact value: (not necessary)
                highestFreqIndex =
                    (OSCILLATOR_HZ * (2 * frequencyBinCount)) / sampleRate;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(highestFreqIndex * step, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(highestFreqIndex * step, scale * 255);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
                ctx.stroke();
                highestFreqHz =
                    (highestFreqIndex * sampleRate) / (2 * frequencyBinCount);
                window.HZ = highestFreqHz;
            }
        }
        // Draw Audio
        this.audioAnalyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.audioBuffer);
        {
            const iv = highestFreqHz == 0 ? 0 : 1 / highestFreqHz;
            const bufferSize = this.audioBuffer.length;
            const offsetY = -this.canvas.height / 2.4;
            const startIndex = Math.round(iv * sampleRate);
            const step = this.canvas.width / (this.audioBuffer.length - startIndex);
            const scale = this.canvas.height / (3 * 255);
            const offsetX = highestFreqHz == 0
                ? 0
                : Math.round((this.context.currentTime % iv) * sampleRate) %
                    bufferSize;
            // Draw the audio graph with the given offset
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-step, this.audioBuffer[startIndex - offsetX] * scale + offsetY);
            for (let i = startIndex; i < bufferSize; i += 4) {
                const index = (i - offsetX) % bufferSize;
                const sample = this.audioBuffer[index];
                ctx.lineTo((i - startIndex) * step, scale * sample + offsetY);
            }
            ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const app = new App(document.getElementById("visualizer"), document.getElementById("options"));
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    function draw() {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        app.drawVisualizer();
    }
});
```

```css
html {
    background: black;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#visualizer {
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Equalizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="visualizer"></div>
    <div id="options"></div>
</body>
</html>
```